# Excel, recursively adding fractions then reset at to zero at 1

Tags: excel

I'm having a little difficulty trying to get an Excel column to recursively add to itself then restart. Basically creating a column that goes:
0, 1/x, 2/x,...,(x-1)/x, 0, 1/x, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MOD` function. First fill a column with numbers 0, 1, 2, etc., then in the desired column write the formula `= MOD(A1, 7)/7` assuming **x = 7**, then drag it.

Comment: Wow, that is exactly what I wanted. Didn't even think about using remainders. Thank you!